# Python Challenge - #3 *spoilers*

Tags: python, loops

After doing some hint searching i have found that i had to `import re` and use regular expressions. The answer is "linkedlist". http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/equality.html

But I am curious what have I done wrong i my previous attempt to solve it?

```
tekstas = "the string that i need to decode"

possible_solution = []

for i in range(0, len(tekstas)):
    if ((ord(tekstas[i]) < 123) and (ord(tekstas[i]) > 96)) and ((ord(tekstas[i-1])) > 64) and ((ord(tekstas[i-1])) < 90) \
    and ((ord(tekstas[i-2])) > 64) and ((ord(tekstas[i-2])) < 90) and ((ord(tekstas[i-3])) > 64) and ((ord(tekstas[i-3])) \
    < 90) and ((ord(tekstas[i+1])) > 64) and ((ord(tekstas[i+1])) < 90) and ((ord(tekstas[i+2])) > 64) and \
    ((ord(tekstas[i+2])) < 90) and ((ord(tekstas[i+3])) > 64) and ((ord(tekstas[i+3])) < 90):
         possible_solution.append(tekstas[i-4]+tekstas[i-3]+tekstas[i-2]+tekstas[i-1]+tekstas[i]+tekstas[i+1]+tekstas[i+2]+\
            tekstas[i+3]+tekstas[i+4])

for i in range (0, len(possible_solution)):
    candidate = possible_solution[i]
    if (ord(candidate[0]) < 123) and (ord(candidate[0]) > 96) and (ord(candidate[8]) < 123) and (ord(candidate[8]) > 96):
        print(candidate[1:8])
```

Answers that i get:
IQNlQSL
OEKiVEY
CNDeHSB
OIXdKBF
CJAsACF
KWGtIDC

small letters that i get from this:liedst 
Why am I missing few letters??

Comment: Where are you testing for **exactly** three big bodyguards? I think you are only testing for *at least* three..

Comment: the first loop looks for atleast three. the next loop looks for exactly three

Comment: And how come your answer includes big letters? Your answer should only include small letters.

Comment: i have included uppercase letters to demonstrate where i find lower case letters

Comment: Why aren't you using a regex? :-)

Comment: at first i havent tought of that. then i have done it with regular expressions. i am curiuous why is this not working

Comment: From your output then you are indeed missing letters from the solution. But your code is so hard to parse, I think I'll pass at trying to debug it. Sorry!

Comment: @MartijnPieters sorry to hear that, maybe i could do smth to improve readability?

Comment: @pptt: Use a separate function to test for lowercase or uppercase letters. Use `'a' <= tekstas[i] <= 'z'` to see if a letter is in the range, no need to use `ord()` and you can chain comparisons. Or use `str.islower()`, `str.isupper()` and `str.isalpha()` instead.

Comment: @pptt I can suggest some stuff to help readability, but it wont fit as either an answer or comments. You can [chat to me about it instead](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84393/chat-with-pptt)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are excluding `Z`, because you are testing your uppercase letters with `(ord(tekstas[i-2])) < 90` rather than `(ord(tekstas[i-2])) < 91`.

Note that you don't need to use `ord()` here at all, you can compare directly to letters:

```
tekstas[i-2] < '['
```

or perhaps more directly recognisable:

```
tekstas[i-2] <= 'Z'
```

You don't need separate `tekstas[i-2] >= 'A' and tekstas[i-2] <= 'Z'` tests either; you could use *chain* the comparisons:

```
'A' <= tekstas[i-2] <= 'Z'
```

The easiest method, however, is to use the [`str.isupper()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isupper):

```
tekstas[i-2].isupper()
```

which for the default locale is only true if *all* characters in the string are uppercase ASCII letters.

That means you can test more than one letter at a time; together with [`str.islower()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.islower) your first `if` test could be reduced to:

```
tekstas[i].islower() and (tekstas[i - 3:i] + tekstas[i + 1:i + 4]).isupper()
```

Comment: Thank you, the Z was indeed excluded. Thanks for detailed examples